# i want to write this query in mysql will you please help me

Tags: mysql

my query is: (Find the names of all classes that either meet in room 115 or have five or more students enrolled.)

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
    sid NUMERIC(6) NOT NULL,
    sname VARCHAR(15),
    major VARCHAR(20),
    level VARCHAR(2),
    sage NUMERIC(2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (sid)
    );
CREATE TABLE CLASS(
    cnum VARCHAR(6),
    meets_at TIME,
    room VARCHAR(6),
    fid NUMERIC(6) ,
    PRIMARY KEY (cnum),
    FOREIGN KEY (fid)
    references FACULTY (fid)     
   );
CREATE TABLE ENROLLED (   
    cnum VARCHAR(6),
    sid NUMERIC(6) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (cnum,sid),
  FOREIGN KEY (sid)
       REFERENCES STUDENT (sid),
        FOREIGN KEY (sid)
       REFERENCES FACULTY (fid),
       FOREIGN KEY (cnum)
       REFERENCES CLASS (cnum)        
    );
  alter table ENROLLED 
   add foreign key (sid)
   references STUDENT (sid);
```

Comment: Have you tried yourself? What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `sid`, `cid` 
FROM (`STUDENT` INNER JOIN `ENROLLED` ON `STUDENT`.`sid` = `ENROLLED`.`sid`) 
    INNER JOIN `CLASS` ON `ENROLLED`.`cnum` = `CLASS`.`cnum` 
GROUP BY `ENROLLED`.`cid` 
HAVING 
    `CLASS`.`room` = '115' OR 
    COUNT(DISTINCT `STUDENT`.`sid`) >= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CLASS
WHERE
    CLASS.room='115'
    OR
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            ENROLLED
            JOIN STUDENT
                ON ENROLLED.sid=STUDENT.sid
        WHERE
            ENROLLED.cnum=CLASS.cnum
    )>=5
```

Comment: Maybe you can accept the answer then? And also remember to up vote the answer you think are good. That gives us all a fuzzy feeling :P